# Changing Inherited Types in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I see there is a similar question asked here but I don't think it was very clear so I'm creating another : [Entity Framework: Inheritance, change object type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239504/entity-framework-inheritance-change-object-type)

I have an Entity Student that inherits from an Entity Person.

At some point a Person could become a Student.

Is there any way in Entity Framework 4 to handle this without a stored procedure or creating a new entity.

Comment: This is a broken object model. In OOP, instances cannot change type. The EF does not add this feature to C#/.NET. You should use composition, not inheritance, for this.

Comment: I was under the impression that it was down to whether a Student IS a Person or whether a Student HAS a Person. Perhaps you could point me to a link where this is defined?

Comment: An object can only have one type. So you can't make a type `RedDog` and also have a type `BigDog`, because a `Dog` can be both big *and* red (Clifford). I wrote about this issue here: http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2008/07/17/37825/

Comment: I see this is an old post, based on EF4. Does this limitation yet exists in the last version of Entity (EF6) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The EF inheritance does not support this scenario. The best way to create a *Student* for an existing *Person* is to use a **stored procedure**. 

Please note that this is not a stored procedure that is wired up to the *Student* entity through mappings, but a separate one that can be called explicitly from code. Ideally it would be a SP that takes a *PersonID* as a parameter, inserts a new row into the *Student* table using that *PersonID*, and then returns a complete *Student* so that it can be used immidiately.

Comment: Just burned by this. There goes an hour I will never get back!