# Changing saved Entity to a new Type without removing

Tags: c#, frameworks, entity

i had a question with changing a saved entity to a new Type, for Example:

I have a root class called Node, a inherited class called material, from material there are two classes inherited from material, textile and the second called compound

in the database a have now 4 Tables, called: Node, Material, Textile, Compound

When i create a Material and saved it, i have rows in Node and Material.

Now i want to change A Material to a Textile, how can i do this? I don't want to remove the material first and create a new Textile, my plan is to update the material entity to textile entity.

is this possible?

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Changing Inherited types is not supported in EF out of the box. Normally one creates stored procedure that handles this change at SQL level, you might want to have a [look here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823662/changing-inherited-types-in-entity-framework/3823925#3823925)