# Create a derived type in Entity Framework Table-Per-Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, table-per-type

Basically, I have two EF classes (mapped to the database) in a TPT architecture:

```
// Gets mapped to a table called "People".
public class Person { public Guid Id { get; set; } }
// Gets mapped to a table called "People_Student".
public class Student : Person {}
```

Now, say I get a Person:

```
var person = context.People.Find(<someguid>);
```

And, subsequently, I want to promote that Person to a Student type and save it back to the database.  I have thought of a few different ideas on how this might work, but I was wondering if there is a best practice for this type of requirement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework: Inheritance, change object type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239504/entity-framework-inheritance-change-object-type)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823662/changing-inherited-types-in-entity-framework/3823925#3823925

Comment: Right you are!  I apparently don't know how to search.

Comment: Not possible.  See:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239504/entity-framework-inheritance-change-object-type

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3823662/changing-inherited-types-in-entity-framework/3823925#3823925